# How to concat duplicates from an array of objects and delete one of them

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to check if in an array of objects I have duplicates `date`, then I have to concat the duplicate obj with `name` and remove one of them.

This is what I could do:

```js
var arr = [
    {name: "Adam", date: "25/11/2022" },
    {name: "Jorge", date: "25/11/2022" },
    {name: "Lucas", date: "24/11/2022" },
    {name: "Bob", date: "23/11/2022" }
]

function getUniqueListBy(arr, key) {
    return [...new Map(arr.map(item => [item[key], item])).values()]
}

const arr1 = getUniqueListBy(arr, 'date')
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1))
```

What I need is this result:

```
var arr1 = [{"name":"Adam / Jorge","date":"25/11/2022"},{"name":"Lucas","date":"24/11/2022"},{"name":"Bob","date":"23/11/2022"}]
```

So the object with duplicated date would be like this:

```
{"name":"Adam / Jorge","date":"25/11/2022"}
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: maybe instead of an Object you could use a Set? Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: maybe not the best solution but why not build a new array with date as key and then add the names to the dates so u can do in the next step recreate the output u want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "Adam", date: "25/11/2022" },
  { name: "Jorge", date: "25/11/2022" },
  { name: "Lucas", date: "24/11/2022" },
  { name: "Bob", date: "23/11/2022" },
];

const result = Object.entries(
  arr.reduce((prev, { date, name }) => {
    prev[date] = prev[date] ? prev[date] + " / " + name : name;
    return prev;
  }, {})
).map(([date, name]) => ({ name, date }));

console.log(result);
```

Using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [
    {name: "Adam", date: "25/11/2022" },
    {name: "Jorge", date: "25/11/2022" },
    {name: "Lucas", date: "24/11/2022" },
    {name: "Bob", date: "23/11/2022" }
];

const grouped = {};
arr.forEach(({name, date}) =>
  (grouped[date] || (grouped[date] = [])).push(name)
);

const result = {};
Object.entries(grouped).forEach(([date, names]) =>
  result[names.join(' / ')] = date
);

console.log(result);
```